# Servo control using dsPIC33's Output Compare and Timers

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, servo

I am trying to control a single servo using output compare and a couple of timers. Timer 2 provides the 20ms period and it controls output compare 1 (OC1). OC1 is running in continuous pulse mode, where it uses Timer 2 to count from 0 to anywhere from 0.8-2.2ms. In my code, I have a function called servo_pos() that calculates the needed value for this time, which is placed in the OC1's OC1RS register.

I am able to set the servo position to whatever angle I want at initialization. Currently at initialization, the servo is set to rotate to the neutral 90 degree position and it stays there. However, I want to be able to change position when I tell it to and my servo won't let me do that. For example, I am using a different timer, Timer 4, to create a 2 second delay. Each time Timer 4 reaches its period count, an ISR is called that is supposed to change the servo position using my servo_pos() function. I know the ISR works because I have an LED blinking every 2 seconds. When the OC1RS register is written a new value, my servo seems to try to move to the new position but it seems as if it is fighting to stay at the neutral position (or whatever position I assign it at initialization). My code is given below, if anyone could please try to help me figure out my problem. I've never used a servo before.

```
#include <p33EV256GM102.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#pragma config ICS = PGD3
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF

//Fosc=7.37MHz
//Fcy=Fosc/2=3.685MHz (No changes to PLL)
#define Fcy 3685000

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __auto_psv__)) _T4Interrupt(void);

void servo_pos(int stop_time);
int pos = 1500;

int main(void)
{
    TRISBbits.TRISB6 = 0; //LED output

    RPOR0bits.RP35R = 0b010000;     //remap pin rp35 as OC1
    ANSELBbits.ANSB3 = 0;           //sets RB3 to digital
    TRISBbits.TRISB3 = 0;           //RB3 output for OC1

    // set servo to neutral position at startup
    OC1R = 0;                    // pulse start time
    servo_pos(pos);             // move servo to neutral position
    OC1CON1bits.OCM = 0b101;    // continuous pulse mode

    // Configure Timer 2 (default timer for output compare)
    PR2 = 9213;             // Timer 2 period (20ms) Fcy x 20ms / 8
    T2CONbits.TCKPS = 0b01; // Timer 2 prescaler 1:8
    T2CONbits.TON = 1;      // Enable Timer 2


    // Configure Timer 4 for controlling how long the servo performs each action
    IPC6bits.T4IP = 1;
    IFS1bits.T4IF = 0;
    IEC1bits.T4IE = 1; 
    PR4 = 28789;                // Timer 4 period (2s) Fcy x 2s / 256
    T4CONbits.TCKPS = 0b11;     // Timer 4 prescaler 1:256
    T4CONbits.TON = 1;          // Enable Timer 4


    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}

void servo_pos(int stop_time) //stop time in microseconds
{
    // Configure Output Compare channel 1 (OC1)
    OC1RS = ((float)stop_time/1000000.0)*Fcy/8; // pulse stop time (1.5ms) OC1RS = Fcy x 1.5ms / 8
}

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __auto_psv__)) _T4Interrupt(void)
{
    // Clear Timer 4 interrupt flag
    IFS1bits.T4IF = 0;
    // Toggle LED on RD1
    LATBbits.LATB6 = ~LATBbits.LATB6;

    servo_pos(pos += 50); //every time ISR is called, change the servo position

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem: my microcontroller was apparently resetting each time the servo was activated because of too much current draw. So I got it working by supplying a separate voltage source to the servo.

Comment: If anyone has a solution that would allow me to use just one supply that would be great.

Comment: Well, the motor itself probably draws a lot when it first starts, so a single supply would need a lot of surge capacity to keep from triggering the MCU's brownout detector.  (you are using it, right? to avoid running code incorrectly and corrupting itself?)  And then there's noise from the commutator and/or internal controller while it's running.

Comment: Given those two problems, I would NOT connect the servo and the MCU power directly together, but run the servo more or less directly from the power source with lots of local capacitance, then run the MCU power through a filter and maybe even a diode to keep the servo from draining the MCU's supply caps.

Comment: @AaronD, as far as I know, I am not using the brownout detector unless it's on by default. I'll try your suggestions thanks.

Comment: I don't know if that chip has it on by default or not, but I like to verify the entire chip anyway just so I know what to expect.  I always use the brownout detector because low voltage can cause weird errors that can be very difficult to track down if you don't expect that cause.  2+2=5 is only the mild side of it.  Imagine that kind of error when calculating the next instruction pointer...

Answer (score 0):

General RC motors require a servo signal update every 20ms.  The behavior if this is not maintained is not well defined - and inconsistent - between manufacturers.  Change your 2s timer to 20ms and you should be fine.

Generally, with the PIC24/dsPIC33 series, you can trigger one timer using the output of another.  Use the 20ms timer to trigger the shorter timer in 'one-shot' mode (you probably already have it in one-shot mode).

The other option is to operate a single PWM timer with a period of 20ms and a very low duty cycle (0.8ms to 2.2ms, as you stated), but you tend to lose resolution using this method.

The two-timer method will be reasonably easy to implement from whre you are and you can keep your resolution.

Comment: slightlynybbled, thanks for your response. Timer 2 is already controlling the 20ms period. Timer 4 is just there to switch the position every 2 seconds, rather than using a pushbutton, switch, etc. I have the OC1 set to continuous pulse mode, not one shot mode. I don't think that could be my problem though since I can set the servo position to any angle initially.

Comment: Have you checked your output signal on an oscilloscope?

Comment: I've checked it with a logic analyzer. It appears to be working right with a 1.5ms duty cycle and 20ms period.

Comment: So when the above code is executed, your logic analyzer shows a steady 1.5ms?

Comment: It does if I don't change the value in the OC1RS register, i.e. if I keep it at 1.5ms by repeatedly calling servo_pos(pos=1500) in the ISR.

Comment: But you can change the value in the OC1RS register and watch the duty cycle changing?

Comment: Yes, I just looked at it again with a logic analyzer. I have the pulse width initialized at 1.5ms in OC1RS and as soon as the ISR is called the first time, I change it to 2ms indefinitely. The logic analyzer shows the 1.5ms pulses as first then it changes to 2ms pulses. For each case, the period remains constant at 20ms. So I'm not sure what could be the problem...

Comment: I commented out "servo_pos(2000);" in my ISR and added an input with the following code inside the main while loop: `if (PORTAbits.RA2 == 1)
            servo_pos(2200);
        else
            servo_pos(800);` and I am able to control the servo's position like I want to. So I believe my ISR is the problem but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

In your ISR try changing `servo_pos(pos + 50)` To `servo_pos(pos += 50)`

Comment: Good catch, I made an edit. But as it was before, the servo still should have moved its arm by a factor of 50 ms once and stayed there infinitely. But it's fighting to stay where I initialized it at 1.5ms. And when I say "fighting", I mean the servo vibrates because it is trying to rotate the arm to the new position but it can't.

Comment: You should also put a return statement in your functions and check whether 'pos' goes beyond a certain limit. Anyway try it, maybe 50 is not enough for a proper movement and the servo and its pot struggle To keep The position..btw if pos is in millisecs, 1.5s is a bit too much for a control signal

Comment: That can't be it. If I reprogram the micro controller with pos=2000 (2ms) or pos=1000 (1ms), the servo rotates all the way left or all the way right, so I know the limit of the servo. I should be able to call the function from the ISR with any constant value between 1000 and 2000 to change the servo position. And I've tried that but no luck. Maybe my servo is broken, or maybe since it's my first time using one I'm just missing something important.

Comment: Then "pos" is not in ms but in microseconds! Anyway...I stand by my comment: add return statements and ensure that pos stays within reasonable limits (otherwise it will runaway since you're looping in an addition). Try these changes then report back ;-)

Comment: The LED you toggle in The ISR is functioning, right? Not only visually but if you check its output with The oscilloscope The timing and wave are right?

Comment: Yeah the LED works fine. I was able to get closer to my solution by declaring the pos variable as volatile, as well as type casting the OC1RS assignment in servo_pos() to volatile. Now, my servo's arm actually moves to the position I tell it to in the ISR, i.e. servo_pos(2000). BUT, the arm quickly moves back to neutral or whatever initial position I set it to in main. Then it keeps moving back and forth each time the ISR is called. It's as if the OC1RS register repeatedly gets reassigned the value it had at initialization.

Comment: yup, that looks like a flow problem. Can you put a reset catch routine in main? ie. strobe a led right before entering the while loop. that way you see if the init section is executed more than once. Maybe also try lowering the optimization setting in your compiler and (even if it makes little sense now) reenable the timer interrupt right at the end of the isr.

Comment: I tried all that you suggested (except lowering the compiler optimization since I don't know how to). The catch routine before main didn't show any toggling of the led I added, so I guess the initializations aren't repeating. Also, now the servo isn't moving at all, just trying to move, so I'm back to square one. And I didn't even change anything.

Comment: Did you put The catch routine before 'main()' or before 'while(1)' ? It should be INSIDE main but outside while To see any reset

Comment: Yeah I had it before the while loop. I got it halfway figured out by the way, I posted my solution. My PIC was resetting so I fixed it by giving the servo a separate power supply.

Comment: Oh good! Sorry i'm on my Phone  and didn't see your answer, well At least you found The culprit. Glad To hear that. Just as a note, you can feed your servo with its supply voltage (6v~ for hobby RC servos iirc) and use a linear regulator To power The micro.

Comment: Oh really?? Thanks, I was wondering what the best method would be to just use one power source cause I really don't want more than 1

Comment: And don't forget To put decoupling caps like everywhere, because RC servos are noisy as hell

Comment: So the voltage regulator method didn't work out. Every time the servo activated it would drop the voltage from the main supply (7V supply) down to around 2V, so then the regulator input voltage wouldn't be high enough since the minimum input voltage needed is 6.25V.

Comment: It drops from 7v To 2v?? You're starving that poor system! :D Servos use current in the ampere range. Just get a beefier supply and you should be good, check The servo's specs To be sure.